# Access Query + your query does not include the specified expression 'TimeID' as part of the aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my query

your query does not include the specified expression 'TimeID' as part of the aggregate function

```
INSERT INTO dwSalesFacts ( FactID, TimeID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, LocationID, ProductID, Quantity, UnitPrice, Discount )
SELECT COUNT(FactID), dwTime.TimeID, Orders.[Customer ID], Orders.[Employee ID], dwLocation.LocationID, [Order Details].[Product ID], [Order Details].Quantity, [Order Details].[Unit Price], [Order Details].Discount
FROM Orders, dwTime, dwLocation, [Order Details];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `COUNT(FactID)` in your `SELECT` statement you need to specify the `GROUP BY` like so:

```
GROUP BY dwTime.TimeID, Orders.[Customer ID], 
  Orders.[Employee ID], dwLocation.LocationID, 
  [Order Details].[Product ID], [Order Details].Quantity, 
  [Order Details].[Unit Price], [Order Details].Discount
```

Whether or not that is what you want the count grouped on I don't know, but based on your select that is what it would have to be.

If `FactID` is an autonumber field then you don't even need to specify it.  Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO dwSalesFacts (TimeID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, LocationID, 
    ProductID, Quantity, UnitPrice, Discount)
SELECT t.TimeID, o.[Customer ID], o.[Employee ID], l.LocationID, 
    od.[Product ID], od.Quantity, od.[Unit Price], od.Discount
FROM Orders AS o, dwTime AS t, dwLocation AS l, [Order Details] AS od
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing it right.  FactID is an autonumber in the new table.  It was my understanding that I needed to use COUNT(FactID) to do this but when I run the query with what you gave me it is prompting me to enter something for FactID

Comment: *@user3043313*, I updated my answer.  Note I added the aliases just to clean up the query.  They are not necessary.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: It didn't give any errors but Access locks up each time I run that.  Have closed Access several times and it keeps hanging when I run that.

Comment: It is probably working and not really locked up.  Have you tried running `SELECT t.TimeID, o.[Customer ID], o.[Employee ID], l.LocationID, od.[Product ID], od.Quantity, od.[Unit Price], od.Discount FROM Orders AS o, dwTime AS t, dwLocation AS l, [Order Details] AS od` and see how long it takes to run?  Also, after you got back into the database, did you check the `dwSalesFacts` to see if it had any new records?  I am guessing it probably does.

Comment: With the INSERT statement you have, it is grabbing every record found in the tables of the SELECT statement and adding them to the `dwSalesFacts` table.  Depending on how many records that is it could take awhile and Access will appear locked as it is being accomplished.

Comment: Instead of just using `FROM Orders, dwTime, dwLocation, [Order Details]` I would suggest JOINing them tables together via the primary and foreign keys.

Comment: The select statement took less than a second.  I let the insert statement run this time and after several minutes it returned the records for insert.  I guess I'm missing something else because I let it run and it is trying to add almost 7 million records.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: *@user3043313*, That is because you are not JOINing the tables together properly.  I would suggest you figure out how to join the tables together via their primary and foreign keys.  If you have any question on how to just post another question with the table formats.  If I answered your question here, can you click on the check mark to set this answer as the accepted answer?